# 1 final mouseout fires after pointer-events disabled

Tags: javascript, css, babeljs, pointer-events

My scenario is I listen to 'click' & 'mouseout' events on a div. When the click event fires, a class is added to the div to disable pointer-events. This works except that 1 final 'mouseout' event will fire after pointer-events have been disabled. Any ideas why/ how to fix?

http://codepen.io/BradLee/pen/grzrOz

```
/* style */
.nopointer{
    pointer-events: none;
}


let div = document.querySelector(`div`);

div.onclick = function() {
    console.log('click!');
    div.classList.add(`nopointer`);

};

div.onmouseout = function() {
  console.log('mouseout!');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting the pointer of the mouse styles confused with actual events firing.

All it seems you are doing is hiding the mouse pointer. If you want to disable click or mouse events you must do so by attaching an event listener. Listen for the event and add

```
document.on("mouseleave","#elementid",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

if you are using jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Remove the backticks in your code and use single quotes instead.

[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/rahul-desai/pen/XdqdXX)

```
console.clear();

let div = document.querySelector('div');

div.onclick = function() {
    console.log('click!');
    div.classList.add('nopointer');

};

div.onmouseout = function() {
  console.log('mouseout!');
};
```

---

**EDIT:**

Reset the `mouseout` event handler in the `onclick` handler:

```
div.onclick = function() {
    console.log('click!');
    div.classList.add('nopointer');
    div.onmouseout = undefined;
};
```

[Edited CodePen](http://codepen.io/rahul-desai/pen/XdqdXX)

Also, you can improve your code further by using the `this` keyword which will point to the `div` itself:

```
div.onclick = function() {
    console.log('click!');
    this.classList.add('nopointer');
    this.onmouseout = undefined;
};
```

Comment: that does not solve the issue. Backticks are allowed as I'm using babel

Comment: @BradWoods Please see my EDIT above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the addEventListener and removeEventListener functions like this:

```
let div = document.querySelector('div');

div.onclick = function() {
    console.log('click!');
    this.classList.add('nopointer');
    div.removeEventListener("mouseleave", mymouseout);
};

function mymouseout() {
  console.log('mouseout!');
}

div.addEventListener("mouseleave", mymouseout);
```